# TSQLConnection connection parameters

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I'm trying to dynamically define the IP address and port of the DataSnap client.

`TSQLConnection` is created in design time, and all other parameters are defined in advance, only have to define the hostname and port in run time and to open connection.

I have tried the following:

```
try 
  con.Params.Values['HostName'] :=  Edit2.Text;
  con.Params.Values['port'] :=  Edit1.Text;
  con.Connected := True;
except
  on e:exception do
  begin
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
  end;
end;`
```

it raises an error

> Item not found

I can't understand that missing item.

Even if everything is defined in advance and that in the run time just open the connection, I get the result that the missing item. If I open the connection in the design time, everything works flawlessly.

Thanks in advance

Bojan

Comment: You need to add some details to your q:  1.  What exact line of your code does the exception occur on, "con.Connected := True" or somewhere else?  2.  Which db type are you trying to access, e.g. MS Sql Server, Interbase, mySql, Sqlite, etc?  They all require different parameters to be specified for the SqlConnection, and some, like Interbase may require environment variables to exist, which may be why your connection works in the IDE but not in your app.  3.  Which Delphi version?  Also please add all your params.

Comment: @MartynA, regarding 2.: if I read it correctly he mentions DataSnap.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Yes, he does, thanks.  But I wasn't sure whether he meant DataSnap as in the name of the DataSnap driver which is available in the drop-down TSqlConnection Driver property list in recent Delphi versions or "datasnap" in the loose, generic sense of using ClientDataSets in the client app, as I've seen done occasionally.  It would be good if he could clarify regardless.

Comment: The driver name is DataSnap, and server database is FireBird. But have only problem in the client part - DataSnap or third tier in 3-tier application. Error is in line con.connected := True. No difference if I use con.open. Only if I open connection in design time there is no error. Delphi version is XE5

Comment: @MartynA "which may be why your connection works in the IDE but not in your app. 3" Application works with and without IDE. Problem is I can't open DataSnap connection in run time.

Comment: DriverUnit=Data.DBXDataSnap
    HostName=192.168.1.38
    Port=1002
    CommunicationProtocol=tcp/ip
    DatasnapContext=datasnap/
     DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=19.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
    Filters={} That are con.Params.

Comment: Sorry, you said "If I open the connection in the design time, everything works flawlessly." which means it works in the IDE at design time, doesn't it?  Also, I don't follow "Application works with and without IDE." since almost by definition it isn't "working" if it can't connect.  Anyway, I'm not meaning to argue, just to understand.  The extra details in your other comments may be sufficient to reproduce your problem I'll try later.

Comment: Let me explain in more detail. When I said "If I open the connection in the design time," I mean specifically to check in the Object Inspector con.Connected as true.

Comment: If I don't check Con.Connected in the Object Inspector but try to open it, for example on buttonClick with con.open; or con.Connected := True; it raises mentioned error.

Comment: Ok, that does seem strange.  One more question if I may:  Is your DataSnap server accessing the stand-alone Firebird server, or the embedded one (based on fbembed.dll)?

Comment: Time to run a debug session?

Comment: Server application access to the Firebird server.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe - I didn't understood your question/comment.

Comment: Well, run the client in debug mode and see where the exception happens.

Comment: it fails in function procedure TDBXClientConnection.DerivedOpen; in line FDbxWriter.Flush; unit Data.DBXClient

Comment: Looks like the error is at the server side. In that case you should debug the server.

Comment: But server sends and communicate with versions connected in the design time, and works correct with them.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with a MySQLDriver.  Maybe it's the same issue, if it helps I'll explain how i solved it:

```
con.Params.Values['port'] :=  Edit1.Text;  is the incorrect.
```

The 'Port' parameter does not exist in MySQL drivers.   You have to use 'Server Port' instead.  Maybe its the same problem with FireBird.